# Signup link for unregistered users on Area51 Discussion Zone does not allow registering

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login

It's pretty common for folks to create unregistered accounts on Area51: following or committing to a proposal when not logged in prompts for an email address and cheerfully creates a new unregistered account.

On the main site, this adds a "register" link to the top bar:

[image: register]

...that takes you to http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login:

[image]

However, if you end up on [the discuss site](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), the UI is a bit more... Insisting:

[image: Finish signing up for your account]

All well and good, I suppose - except that those links *do not* take you to http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login; instead, they go to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered:

[image]

But hey, inconsistency is the spice of life, right? Both login forms look like they provide the same functionality, so let's just click "Sign up using Google" and get on with our lives...

[image: 404!]

Awww...

Well, maybe no one uses Google. Let's try creating an official Stack Exchange login! Enter a password, and away we go...

[image]

Yay! Life is looking better. And within seconds, there's an email in my inbox! Surely this is gonna work... Just to click the link to complete registration, and...

[image: 404!]

Awww.

### Recommendation

Redirect https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered to http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login.

Comment: Each time I saw "Awww." I was hoping for a catpic :(

Comment: The cat shows up when this gets fixed.

Comment: Okay, so this really is broken.  I just signed up for an Area 51 account and am happy to become registered.  So I do it the same way I have at least 1/2 dozen times, I click "google".  Everything seems good.  But intermittently -- e.g., clicking through to a question, I get thrown in this absurd circle.  Short story: I can't even ask there what's wrong.

Comment: I've fixed up your account, @goldilocks - you encountered a slightly different (but related) problem; I'll have to follow up with the devs separately about that.

Comment: Thanks much! :)  All good now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirect will be live in the next build.

Comment: Where's the cat pic? SHOG PROMISED A CAT PIC!!!!ELEVEN

Comment: @Braiam Do I look like I'm Shog9? My head isn't disembodied even a little bit.